# Power Apps Navigate Function

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I am trying to use Navigate function, instead of a Screen Name, I tried to get it from a vairaible, but It says The specified property is not accessible in this context, the code looks like this
Set(ScrnNm,ListEntries1_1.Selected.Label1_1.Text);Navigate(ScrnNm,ScreenTransition.None), it is attached to the 'OnSelect' property of a button on a first screen, ListEntries1_1 (gallery name on first screen).Selected.Label1_1 (Gallery values from a backend Table).Text
Kindly help, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a text variable to navigate to a screen - you need to use the screen *reference* itself. One option is to use a Switch statement that would check the value of your label, similar to the example below:

```
Set(
    screenToNavigate,
    Switch(
        ListEntries_1.1.Selected.Label1_1.Text,
        "Screen1", Screen1,
        "Screen2", Screen2,
        "Screen3", Screen3));
Navigate(screenToNavigate, ScreenTransition.None)
```